# Add printer VBS Script SWbemObjectEx Access denied

Tags: group-policy, printer, vbscript

The script runs fine when run as admin on the local computer, but when deployed via GPO as a startup script gets 'access denied' from SWbemObjectEx.put_. Here's the whole script:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

On Error Resume Next
''--- in case the driver is already there
REM *** Installs printer driver needed for Universal PS 64 Bit
Set objDriver = objWMIService.Get("Win32_PrinterDriver") 
objDriver.Name = "HP Universal Printing PS" 
objDriver.FilePath = "\\share$\Drivers\Printers\HP\HP-Universal\x64\" 
objDriver.InfName = "\\share$\Drivers\Printers\HP\HP-Universal\x64\hpcu155v.inf"
objDriver.SupportedPlatform = "Windows NT x64" 
objDriver.Version = "3" 
errResult = objDriver.AddPrinterDriver(objDriver) 

rem *** Installs a TCP/IP printer local port on a computer
Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get _
 ("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_
objNewPort.Name = "IP_172.17.87.226"
objNewPort.Protocol = 1
objNewPort.HostAddress = "172.17.87.226"
objNewPort.PortNumber = "9100"
objNewPort.SNMPCommunity = "public"
objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False
objNewPort.Put_

rem *** installs printer 
Set objPrinter = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Printer").SpawnInstance_
objPrinter.DriverName = "HP Universal Printing PS" 
objPrinter.PortName = "IP_172.17.87.226"
objPrinter.DeviceID = "HP LaserJet P2055dn in TPCS-400"
objPrinter.Shared = False
objPrinter.Location = "TPCS-400"
objPrinter.Put_
```

I used a second version of the script to debug by adding liberal entries like so:

```
writeLineToLog("addPrinterDriver errResult=" & errResult)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    writeLineToLog("Error: " & Err.Number)
    'writeLineToLog("Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number))
    writeLineToLog("Source: " &  Err.Source)
    writeLineToLog("Description: " &  Err.Description)
    Err.Clear
End If
```

and another to determine the current user, here's the output of the debug:

```
starting script at 2/16/2017 2:41:29 PM
addPrinterDriver errResult=0
after Installs a TCP/IP printer local port on a computer
The current user is SYSTEM
after Set objPrinter
after objPrinter.DriverName =
after objPrinter.PortName =
after objPrinter.DeviceID = 
after objPrinter.Shared = 
after objPrinter.Location=
after objPrinter.Put_
after Installs printer
Error: -2147217405
Source: SWbemObjectEx
Description: Access denied
```

The error is coming when the last put_ is tried.

Comment: Updating the driver seemed to fix things but after a few hours  it's back again, so the bounty is on again.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a user or machine GPO Policy? I would suspect if it is user that the actual user might not have permissions to add the printer.

You could try to follow [this guide from MSDN's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/7/2011/07/11/allowing-standard-users-to-install-network-printers-on-windows-7-without-prompting-for-administrative-credentials/) to give the user's access. Though I would personally recommend you deploy printers through the GPO built in functions, which you could find a [guide for here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/02/03/step-by-step-setting-up-printers-via-group-policy/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for why this script, which we have previously deployed successfully to more than 1000 computers,  is now failing, I see many other folks having the same issue when I search but none of the solutions offered fixes the issue for us. The script came from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/41a4c996-b7f7-4d58-808d-2acac20ddbf7 It's deployed as a machine policy.  Note above that when it fails,  it is running as system.

Comment: Also this is a standalone printer, so AFAIK can't be deployed by the method in the guide you linked to as there's no print server, plus it can't be deployed this way either  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754294.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 as it does not show in the list to be selected, so I'm stuck with deploying via script. I have a workaround which is to deploy via SCCM using the exact same script which just works, but I'd still like to know why it won't work as a GPO.